# How to _cloneDeepWith_ with customizer and add properties

Tags: javascript, object, clone, lodash

I am using [cloneDeepWith](https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeepWith) to deeply clone an `Object` and in certain situations like if the `key` is *module*, assign a specific *value* like:

```js
const myObject = {
  foo: [1, 2, 3],
  bar: {
    module: 'lorem ipsum',
    test: 123
  },
  module: 'hello'
}

function customizer(val, key, obj) {
  if (key === 'module') {
    return 'custom'
  }
}

const clonedObject = _.cloneDeepWith(myObject, customizer)

console.log(clonedObject)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.14.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

### Problem

The point is that now I need to *add* some *properties* in cases where a meet a condition. For example, if the `obj` in the iteration has a `key === 'test'`, add some attributes. See code below:

```
const myCustomProps = { a: 'lorem', b: 'ipsum' }

function customizer(val, key, obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty('test')) {

    //---> Hoping could return the Object instead of value, like:
    return Object.assign({}, obj, {
      ...myCustomProps
    })
  }
}

const clonedObject = _.cloneDeepWith(myObject, customizer)
```

Probably *cloneDeepWith* it isn't the right `function` to use, but I couldn't find the right one in the entire Lodash [documentation](https://lodash.com/docs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to perform the cloning and assignment separately. After you have your cloned object, you can recursively call `_.forEach` with a function that assigns the new props. In this example, all objects with key `'test'` will have the new props added.

```js
const myCustomProps = { a: 'lorem', b: 'ipsum' }

const clonedObject = {
  foo: [1, 2, { test: 123 }],
  bar: {
    module: 'custom',
    test: 123,
    baz: {
      test: 123,
    }
  },
  module: 'custom'
}

function iteratee(val) {
  // Base case
  if (!val || (typeof val !== 'object' && !Array.isArray(val))) {
    return
  }

  // Recursively apply iteratee 
  _.forEach(val, iteratee)

  // Perform check
  if (val.hasOwnProperty('test')) {
    Object.assign(val, {...myCustomProps})
  }
}

const result = _.forEach(clonedObject, iteratee)

console.log(clonedObject)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.14.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank @framk-tan for the reply. I thought about this possibility but the issue is that I need to _deeply_ change like in `foo: [1, 2, { test: 123}]` (edited your testing code to show)

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that the customizer's callback is called with the initial object instead of its first element, which results in endless loops.